# How can I draw a Keynesian AS diagram using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to draw a Keynesian AS diagram for my economics coursework. How can I draw it using TikZ (or any other package)? I have tried the `controls` modifier but it couldn't produce a "sharp" curve.

This is the graph I'm trying to draw:
[image]

As you can see, the text box for the dotted lines obstruct the curve.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Not many people on TeX.SX will know what a "Keynesian AS diagram" so when you add your [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) it would be helpful if you can explain what this diagram should look like.

Comment: I know I should add a MWE but the thing is, I don't know where to start. The sample photo was drawn using Microsoft Word. @Troy

Comment: For this graph you probably want to use data visualization with the TikZ package.  Pgfplots does a lot of things you don't really need, like computing the scale to fit the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do as a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-latex](0,0)--(10,0)node[below]{%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      Real\\GDP
    \end{tabular}};
  \draw[-latex](0,0)--(0,10)node[anchor=north east]{%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      General\\Price\\Level
    \end{tabular}};
  \coordinate(P1) at (0,4);
  \coordinate(AS1) at (3.5,8);
  \coordinate(AS2) at (6,8);
  \draw(0.5,7) -- +(6,-6)node[right]{$\text{AD}_1$};
  \draw(1,9) -- +(8,-8)node[right]{$\text{AD}_2$};
  \draw[-latex](1.5,6.5)--+(1.6,0);
  \draw[dashed]({(0,0)} -| AS1)node[below]{$\text{Y}_1$} -- (AS1);
  \draw[thick,rounded corners=7mm](P1) -| (AS1)node[above]{$\text{AS}_1$};
  \draw[dashed]({(0,0)} -| AS2)node[below]{$\text{Y}_2$} -- (AS2);
  \draw[thick,rounded corners=7mm](P1) -| (AS2)node[above]{$\text{AS}_2$};
  \draw[-latex]($(AS1)+(0.3,-1)$) -- ($(AS2)+(-0.3,-1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]